# How to create button shape according to the button image

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

How to draw a button like the shape showed in the image. Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: what you have tried

Comment: you actually don't need to draw a button like this,  if you are using auto layout then just set the horizontal and vertical constraint then just set the image in the button's image property, the button will automatically adjust to the image size.

Comment: currently i'm using normal button. I don't know how to do this

Comment: But i'm not using AutoLayout

Comment: Use button Type as Custom

Answer (score 0):

First see this png icon of like you are shown in question.

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5inJw5CxPH0Ul85Rl9LT3YyVnc](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5inJw5CxPH0Ul85Rl9LT3YyVnc/view)
add this image in your project with name downbutton.

then,

```
UIImage *buttonimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"downbutton"];
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
[button setImage:buttonimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score -1):

SET THE BUTTON BACKGROUD IMAGE. YOUR PROBLEM WILL BE SOLVED :

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

THIS CODE WILL HELP YOU